# "We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries and more."

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions

My [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60007384/open-a-password-protected-pst-file) was closed as "off-topic", I'm trying to understand why. Its message shows:

> We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more. Edit the question so it can be answered with facts and citations. You can edit the question or post a new one.

But there seem to be a gazillion SO questions asking for the correct way to parse a file format, or for the correct way to use a common library.

Why is asking for the algorithm / code / approach / library to solve this particular programming challenge unreasonable?

Comment: [Your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60007384/open-a-password-protected-pst-file) has potential. An edit that adds more details and specific contextual information could rescue the question, and result in it getting re-opened.

Comment: Just gonna air this out.  We probably *shouldn't* downvote this question.  Someone comes to Meta with their hat in hand and wants to understand what they did wrong and how they can avoid it.  We should celebrate that and work with them - irrespective of if the question is/isn't a dupe.

Comment: We probably also shouldn’t tell people how to vote, @Makoto. I agree, however, that this is a *valid* question, and I appreciate the person caring enough to ask.

Comment: @CodyGray:  Sure, but if we keep kicking people when they're down, they'll stop asking for help and [keep calling us toxic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342779/175248).  It's the little things we can at least say or speak up about that'll stop that from becoming another stupid campaign, y'know?

Comment: I cant see the OG question because the author removed it, but this page is the first search result for the 'site error' which is the title. Why not refer people to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ instead of saying "no" and closing people's questions? That comes off as rude and is massively counterproductive.

Answer (score 5):

Since you're looking for ways to improve, I'll volunteer this answer.

Your question is effectively asking for a tool or utility that fulfills your requirements.  It's *not* an individual attempt at programming a solution.

If you had shared some code which suggested that you were having trouble with some existing solution on how to read passwords, that *might* have served as a better question.  For now, I don't see a reason for it to be reopened since it's in this state.

Comment: Thanks, but I mentioned the specific trouble with the solutions I tried in my original question. BTW I also found an interesting solution (work around?) while investigating the issue. I put it in a comment there but then deleted all of it, so as not to offend the SO mods further (with further downvotes).

Comment: where DO people ask for recommended tools / libraries etc.? it's such a common request , and still makes sense. many people would seek out resources when they dont have the time to build one themselves , so its not always a sign of laziness. I think that there could be a separate forum or a subforum of SO that could contain such discussions

Comment: @Andy:  Typically "not on Stack Overflow" is the answer.  In network, [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) exists but I don't reach for it since the notion of asking someone for a tool to use is such a nebulous and difficult to constrain ask that I don't like steering people to incomplete hope.