# Please help to undelete my question that was auto-deleted by a bot so I can do something about it

Tags: discussion, status-declined, specific-question, vote-to-undelete

I asked this question at the beginning of 2023:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74996560/bash-command-line-args-tab-auto-completion-from-a-database-service

With no comments or replies for a few weeks, I came up with an answer on my own.

But the question was auto-deleted by the bot after a month.

Now **nothing** can be done to a question given this banner:

[image]

...  except to ask the community to undelete it.

[image]

Comment: Your question sounds a lot like a "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more" request

Comment: Reading the question, I have no idea how the body relates to the title. The question in the title is likely a duplicate, the question in the body is off-topic. *Why* should this be undeleted? Have you considered to edit it to make it *worth* undeleting?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi the post is laying out a design for what seems to be a service that would use cloud data for autocompletion. Somehow. (I have no idea why the cloud would be useful for this, or why autocompletion of anything practical at the command line should require more than a few KB of data.) But yeah, there doesn't seem to be a question here.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I considred many things - it took me a month to come up with a tool solving that problem. I just didn't know stackoverflow automatically deletes the questions.

Comment: Anyway. We shouldn't have to explain this to someone who has an account over 12 years old with a couple dozen questions spaced out over the years, but the question here (if there is actually a **question** at all) is blatantly off topic. Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, and note well that Stack Overflow is **not a discussion forum**.

Comment: "I just didn't know stackoverflow automatically deletes the questions." Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254262, specifically the section about deletion.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel How does **a question without reply for a month make SO a "discussion forum"**? It asks for a solution to a problem. Solution which simply didn't exist at the time of asking.

Comment: What I am saying is that you treat Stack Overflow like a discussion forum **by the content of the post**. You are describing a design for a project. We don't do top-level design. We require **much more specific** questions. If you wanted the tool to exist already then you are looking for a recommendation for software, which we also don't do. These things are simply off topic. Consider [softwarerecs.se] for the latter. Also, titles aren't a part of the post. The post itself should clarify what "this" is if you want to know whether "something like this" exists.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, :/ I seek no "top-level design", instead the design (you said) was "laid out" to make it *"much more specific"* question. It looks more like SO moderated itself out of useful niche questions (which might be hard to answer immediately) towards those which are answerable quicly by the majority. Asking the same thing on Software Recomendations is a bit too late when I have the answer, right? I simply wanted to address the question **closed by a bot** (not human) for the other larger audience than judges of "content by the look of it" instead of the fact it caused no discussion.

Comment: "I simply wanted to address the question closed by a bot (not human)" - Again, read the link I gave you. "instead the design (you said) was "laid out" to make it "much more specific" question" That doesn't make the question more specific; it **explains why** the question lacks focus. We don't mean "explain every point in the question"; we mean "have exactly one point to explain and the explicitly ask about".

Comment: "Asking the same thing on Software Recomendations is a bit too late when I have the answer, right?" No, not at all. That is not how SE sites work. We're building a library, and have no sense of urgency for answering questions. You can, and are encouraged to, self- answer questions (as long as it isn't, you know, for the purpose of promoting your own project). " It looks more like SO moderated itself out of useful niche questions (which might be hard to answer immediately) towards those which are answerable quicly by the majority" - no, "niche" has **absolutely nothing to do with it**.

Comment: For that matter: you've said a lot about what you think needs to be done in order for the tool to work, but it honestly isn't that clear *what should happen* when the tool is used. "I want to facilitate narrowing down arg values by: service name, cluster name or any other properties" - what does this mean? I assume you are talking about the command line arguments - **of what program**? The names **of what services/clusters**, and **what do they have to do with** the program whose command line you are completing?

Comment: Why should "a database service" be helpful in auto-completing a command? What database is it going to use to look up suggestions, and why is that better than just letting the shell do what it normally does? What command are you trying to auto-complete, and what is insufficient about its built-in autocompletion?

Comment: This isn't a support question, but rather a discussion one; support is for help with understanding or using a site feature; you're simply asking the community to agree with you on the status of a post's deletion or undeletion, which is a matter of debate/discussion.

Comment: @uvsmtid "I considred many things - it took me a month to come up with a tool solving that problem. I just didn't know stackoverflow automatically deletes the questions." I'm not following how that relates to the comprehensibility and focus of the question. Sure, you might have avoided the automatic deletion if you knew its rules, but that doesn't mean that deletion was wrong in itself. The question appears to be *blatantly* unsuitable for SO.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel How is asking a **new** question (**now** when I **know** the answer) with my new project to address it is not a self promotion (what you suggest)? Compare my intention: answering a month old question (asked when no apparent solution existed) with results **plus** a chance to chip in on SO by many others. A new question puts me in risk to face new valid(!) set of restrictions and links. :) So, no, I don't buy this: _"You can, and are encouraged to,"_ **(ask again and)** _"self-answer questions (as long as it isn't, you know, for the purpose of promoting your own project)."_

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, _"I'm not following how that relates to the comprehensibility and focus of the question."_ Maybe because comprehensibility is not in question? My unserstanding the issue was that it ["seeks recommendation in software"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393489/441652). And my POV it is fine, no harm, more use. I also argue there is no problem with focus either. I encaurage you to give at least one answer to fit the tight description of the question. _"The question appears to be blatantly unsuitable for SO"_ - a blatantly bold statement IMO.

Comment: The site provides a close link under a question - go to any question on the main site and click it. Go to "A community-specific reason". See the reasons listed there. Plain and simple. It does not matter what is said here by you or anyone else, that dialog is the cold hard undeniable truth. We do not own the site, we do not make the rules.

Comment: Usually by reading the title, the body, and looking at the tags I can understand what the question is about. In this case I cannot. There are some clues for sure, and some clues that it's off-topic for other reasons, but I'd close it for needing more clarity.

Comment: "How is asking a new question (now when I know the answer) with my new project to address it is not a self promotion (what you suggest)?" **Exactly because "my new project" is how you propose to address it**. If the question needs something as complex as "your new project" to address it, then a) that is out of scope for Stack Overflow questions and b) the answer would be rejected as link-only (answers need to be able to stand on their own; and you presumably are not going to copy and paste all your source code into one answer, while also explaining every aspect of it).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel So it is better to anser old question later, not posting new ones (having answer ready), correct? _"the only apparent reason you have for posting the Q&A now is so that someone else could use your solution"_ = like very SO answer **ever**. :)

Comment: " is so that someone else could use your solution" = like very SO answer ever. :)" - **No, not even remotely**. The reason to post answers on Stack Overflow is to contribute to a knowledge base. That may involve people choosing to **adapt** your **answer** to a **question**, to their particular circumstances. That is worlds apart from downloading and installing and running your software, in order to solve a problem they had that happened to be the exact same one you had.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel _"not even remotely?"_ Really? :) It's getting phylosofical. Replacing "useable solution" -> "knowledge base" just changing the language, not the meaning and the context. Besides, contributing to knowledge base which does not solve problems - why?

Comment: "Replacing "useable solution" -> "knowledge base" just changing the language, not the meaning and the context. " No, there is a very important difference in meaning, that should be obvious. If I read a book about fly fishing, I should not be confronted with ads for tackles and lures, even if they are free and even if they are hand-crafted by the author rather than by a large corporation.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel :) You read "a book about fishing" when you already aquired the book, not when you googling questions (with side Ads) and come to SO browsing through many other "books" (with SO side Ads luring you by job offers). If you think SO is a book by single author, this is a misappropriation.

Comment: To be quite blunt, it comes across that you are interested in justifying your own actions and picking apart analogies, and not interested in accepting that you were wrong and that your proposal was against policy. I am done talking about this.

Comment: None of this really matters, the question is currently off topic and no edit has been provided to remedy that. What purpose the network serves is mostly irrelevant to your situation.

Comment: @KevinB _"no edit has been provided to remedy that"_ (1) Request to undelete was to revive the question and remedy that in the first place. (2) Not a single comment was made on the question (screenshot) which suggests that there is nothing wrong with the question, indicating no apparent answers! And, perhaps, a downvote per months - apparently from a confromists propoting each other here. :) What else matters?

Comment: None of that matters, still, as the question is still off topic.

Comment: @KevinB Would it matter [if I could improve it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423069/please-help-to-undelete-my-question-that-was-deleted-by-the-roomba-so-i-can-answ#comment946317_423070)

Comment: If there were any chance it could be improved, yes. In this case, the only improvement you could make would be turning it into an entirely different question... which isn't a reasonable reason to undelete

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your question was deleted automatically by the [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) due to its negative score. However, if it were undeleted, it would be closed due to being a recommendation request for an off-site tool or resource, and would likely just be deleted again (and rightly so).

While it may sometimes be OK to suggest a tool or library as an *answer* to a question (though usually some examples of how said tool answers its respective question are expected), it is never OK to outright *ask* for a tool or library here on Stack Overflow. We actually have a sister site dedicated for that kind of question: [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour).

You may be thinking "well, if I just change my question from 'is there a tool that does X,Y,Z' to 'How can I achieve X,Y,Z'", then please hold your horses; such a request is far too broad (qualifying for the close reason of "Needs Focus") because it would require someone to write an entire library (as you found out first-hand) to address. Questions on Stack Overflow should be specific, and reasonably-scoped. In other words, if it takes a blog post or a library to fully address the needs of a question, the question is too broad for Stack Overflow.

I see you have never taken the site [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). I recommend you do that, and then review the [On-Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page of the Help Center if you have any further concerns.

Comment: "Statistically, do undelete requests mostly cause a repeated discussion for self promotion" Only when the undelete request appears to involve the desire to post a link to off-site code that completes a task, as opposed to **answering a question** that is part of a proper, searchable library.

Comment: @uvsmtid - A moderator had nothing to do with your question being deleted. Your question received a downvoted (likely due to the fact it wasn't within scope), likely so little to no views, which is the reason it was deleted due to inactivity. Your question has not been edited since it was deleted, so it's ineligible to be restored, since in it's current form it's still out of scope. **The community typically will undelete a contribution not a moderator.**

Comment: @SecurityHound I understand why the quetion is auto-deleted by a bot. I talk to moderators assuming they judge consiously (not automatically 1 downvote, 1 month old -> delete) and understand the harmful or beneficial consequences for SO and users looking for answers in that specific case. And I don't understand the moderators. What harm? Given no user gave suggestion to improve the question, the question is simply pending an answer. Why not let users judge?

Comment: @uvsmtid Users did judge, by at best avoiding the question. The OP (in this case, you) is the only one who is the closest to being responsible to improve the question. That no one found the question useful or worth making it useful isn’t really a good sign…

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I don't think you understand - there is no way to improve anything if the question is deleted. There is also no way to know what to improve if there were no prior comments to that. Why not retry? If bot is just automatic. Isn't it what moderators are for?

Comment: @uvsmtid You should still be able to edit the question, and it can still be undeleted. See [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) (at the bottom) on advice how to proceed. "There is also no way to know what to improve if there were no prior comments to that." It looks like you have received plenty of comments here already; if you need more, asking for them seems prudent.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, the keyword is **prior**. To have this fruitful discussion, it had to be auto-deleted in a month, everyone had to spend time here. And at the end, the new question I'll ask will likely have no immediate answers (I've done the research already) than the one I was going to post anyway. So what is the role of moderator solving here for users? Another auto-bot? :)

Comment: @uvsmtid The **prior** is a keyword only because you insist on it. You can **still** edit the question. You can **still** ask for and react to feedback. You can **still** get it undeleted and answer it yourself. So what is the role you think a moderator should be solving here for users? **You** are the one who can solve this.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I tried, see [the birght yellow banner here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423069/441652). **Still** is your theory. :) Mine one is that this process is only useful for moderators to upvote each other.

Comment: Just as a heads-up: writing things like "X is your theory. :)" when you are **being told how the site works, by experienced users who are regulars on Meta** is really not the sort of thing that gets people on your side.